# Python: Looping through all parameter options

Tags: python, loops, parameters

I wrote a code that uses a parameter in certain file names, locations, etc. (simplified below):

```
file_type = sys.argv[1]
[...]
parent_folder = 'C:/path/to/dir/'
input_folder = parent_folder + file_type + '_inventory'
output_folder = parent_folder + file_type + '_export'
```

So the parameter `file_type` can be `FOO`, `BAR`, or `FOOBAR`, and that will determine which dir/files are used. But, I have been trying to find a more robust way to incorporate `ALL` into this parameter.

Currently, I have `IF` `ELSE` statements, where one option has my script copied multiple times with each parameter choice hardcoded in; for when `file_type` = `ALL`. There should be a way to have it loop through a set of values/strings instead of duplicating the code, but I have not been able to find any semblance of it.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate more.

Comment: Hi physlexic.  Yes, you'll have to elaborate more.  You mention you have `if/else` statements, but you're not showing them to us.  As it stands, there's nothing we can do to answer your question.  Please read [ask], and look into creating a [mcve].  Then [edit] your question with an example we can work with, and you'll be much more likely to get the answer you need.

Comment: "where one option has my script copied multiple times with each parameter choice hardcoded in" I don't follow.

Comment: One option is to make `input_folder` and `output_folder` into globs, by replacing `ALL` with `*`.

Comment: You might want to consider stepping back and designing a standard Unix-style API where you can use multiple args or flags to specify file types instead of just hardcoded `argv[1]` (e.g., with `argparse`), and then just define ALL to mean the list of all valid types, treated no differently from an explicit list of types. That might be overkill for this project, but even just thinking about it in those terms without trying to build it might help you think through the rest of the code.

Comment: Anyway, if you turn your whole program into an otherwise-pointless loop over `for typ in [file_type]:`, then it seems pretty easy to handle `ALL`. Just do something like `types = ['FOO', 'BAR', 'FOOBAR'] if file_type == 'ALL' else [file_type]`, and then you can loop over `types`.

Comment: For this case, so long as your existing code is working, you might be better off posting your full code to codereview.stackexchange.com and asking for ideas for how to improve it (specifically to refactor it to reduce code duplication).  The best answer might not have anything to do with loops, but it's not clear from your current problem statement.

Comment: @abarnert thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for. i used `if file_type == 'all' : types = [...]' else : [...]`.. you can answer this thread so i can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to *always* loop over your whole program, once for each file type. If a single file type is specified, you just loop over that one type, but if `all` is specified, you loop over all of them.

For example, we can create a single-element list of just `[sys.argv[1]]`, except when it's `ALL`:

```
file_types = [sys.argv[1]] if sys.argv[1] != 'ALL' else ['FOO', 'BAR', 'FOOBAR']
for file_type in file_types:
    [...]
    parent_folder = 'C:/path/to/dir/'
    input_folder = parent_folder + file_type + '_inventory'
    output_folder = parent_folder + file_type + '_export'
```